# Using time based transient property with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `Event` model with `startDate` and `endDate`. I want to sort this event to 3 categories.

- Current: startDate < today < endDate
- Upcoming: today < startDate
- Past: endDate < today

I made a transient property called `status` contain above logic and use this as parameter in `NSFetchedResultsController`

> NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
>   managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:
>   "status", cacheName: nil)

When I run I got this error telling me to use section as sort descriptor.

> CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at
>   index 2 has an out of order section name '1. Objects must be sorted by
>   section name'

I then set this in sort descriptor and got this error, since transient can't be used as sort descriptor.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath status not found in
>   entity '

The problem is this section are determine from 2 properties, so it can't be sort by just `startDate` or `endDate`, but both.

What is the best way to solve this problem? I have consider making this status non-transient, but this value is updated daily, I think it kind of weird to make it non-transient.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchedResultsController` cannot sort on a transient property if it is backed by SQLite (which is the usual case). The backend has to turn your sort request into a SQL query, and the query won't have access to transient properties. You either have to make status non-transient or you can't use `NSFetchedResultsController` for this.

See the [Core Data Programming Guide: Advanced Topics: Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1) for more.

> In addition you cannot sort on transient properties using the SQLite store.